# Both web and mobile AOuth2 with Silhouette

Tags: playframework, silhouette

After a successful google-web login with play-framework+silhouette, I want to be able to access with an ajax request.
[This answer](http://silhouette.mohiva.com/discuss/558b8b6f86c5d40d00483a19) says to use 2 controllers wit 2 environments.

```
 Environment[User, SessionAuthenticator]
 Environment[User, JWTAuthenticator]
```

1. How can I "link" the web authentication (SessionAuthenticator) with other parts that uses the JWTAuthenticator
2. Can the ajax client use the data in the session cookie to construct the JWT header (how)?

Answer (score 0):

```
Implement aouth2 with User define tables.
 public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        app.MapSignalR();

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
call startup class 
ConfigureOAuth(app);
  public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),
             RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider()
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

    }
Provider -----
  public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
        {
            var user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }



        //ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await _repo.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
        //      context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        //ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await _repo.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
        //    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        //AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        //AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        //context.Validated(ticket);
        //context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
 }
           var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

        context.Validated(identity);

    }

    public override async Task GrantRefreshToken( OAuthGrantRefreshTokenContext context)

    {
        var originalClient = context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary["as:client_id"];
        var currentClient = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:client_id");

        // enforce client binding of refresh token
        if (originalClient != currentClient)
        {
            context.Rejected();
            return;
        }

        // chance to change authentication ticket for refresh token requests
        var newId = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Ticket.Identity);
        newId.AddClaim(new Claim("newClaim", "refreshToken"));

        var newTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(newId, context.Ticket.Properties);
        context.Validated(newTicket);
    }
}

public class SimpleRefreshTokenProvider : IAuthenticationTokenProvider
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthenticationTicket> _refreshTokens = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthenticationTicket>();


    public   async Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        // maybe only create a handle the first time, then re-use
        _refreshTokens.TryAdd(guid, context.Ticket);

        // consider storing only the hash of the handle
        context.SetToken(guid);
    }

    public   async Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        AuthenticationTicket ticket;
        if (_refreshTokens.TryRemove(context.Token, out ticket))
        {
             context.SetTicket(ticket);
        }
    }

    public void Create(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        // maybe only create a handle the first time, then re-use
        _refreshTokens.TryAdd(guid, context.Ticket);

        // consider storing only the hash of the handle
        context.SetToken(guid);
    }

    public void Receive(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        AuthenticationTicket ticket;
        if (_refreshTokens.TryRemove(context.Token, out ticket))
        {
            context.SetTicket(ticket);
        }
    }
}
 Repo-------------
  public class UserManagerService : UserManager<User>, IUserManagerService<User>
{

    public UserManagerService(IUserStore<User> userStore)
        : base(userStore)
    {
        this.UserValidator = new UserValidator<User>(this) { AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false };
    }

    public new IUserStore<User> Store
    {
        get { return base.Store; }
    }


}


  public class AuthRepository : IDisposable
  {
   private AuthContext _ctx;

   private UserManager<User> _userManager;

   public AuthRepository() 
   {
       _ctx = new AuthContext();
       _userManager =  new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(_ctx));
   }
   //public async Task<IdentityResult> RegisterUser(UserModel userModel)
   //{
   //    IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser
   //    {
   //        UserName = userModel.UserName
   //    };

   //    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userModel.Password);

   //    return result;
   //}

   public async Task<User> FindUser(string userName, string password)
   {
       User user = await _userManager.FindAsync(userName, password);

       return user;
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
       _ctx.Dispose();
       _userManager.Dispose();

   }
   }


  public class AuthContext : DbContext
 {
   public AuthContext()
       : base("ObjectContext")
   {
   }
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {

       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(i => i.Id).ToTable("Roles");
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().HasKey<string>(i => i.Id).ToTable("Users");
       modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey<string>(i => i.Id).ToTable("Users");
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().HasKey<int>(i => i.Id).ToTable("UserClaims");
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey(q => new { q.LoginProvider, q.UserId, q.ProviderKey }).ToTable("UserLogins");
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(q => new { q.RoleId, q.UserId }).ToTable("UserRoles");

       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   }
}
```

Comment: Silhouette and play are Scala (or Java) solutions. you code reminds me C#. Is it so?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a complete technical solution but these are my insights:

1. it is possible to embed both cookie session and X-Auth-Token on the "login-response". they are placed on headers with different names.
2. In order to generate both you will need the 2 relevant "Environment"s on the login controller.
3. After login your client will have both cookies (whatever the cost is) but afterwards the secured requests to SilhouetteController only handle one type of auth per controller (with "com.mohiva" %% "play-silhouette" % "2.0" I think it changed in Silhouette 3.0)